# How to make destructor wait until other thread's job complete?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have one main thread that will send an async job to the task queue on the other thread. And this main thread can trigger a destroy action at any time, which could cause the program to crash in the async task, a piece of very much simplified code like this:

```
class Bomb {
public:
    int trigger;
    mutex my_mutex;
};

void f1(Bomb *b) {
    lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(b->my_mutex); //won't work! Maybe b have been destructed!
    sleep(1);
    cout<<"wake up.."<<b->trigger<<"..."<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    Bomb *b = new Bomb();
    b->trigger = 1;
    thread t1(f1, b);
    sleep(1);
    //lock here won't work
    delete b;//in actual case it is triggered by outside users
    
    t1.join();

    return 0;
}
```

The lock in f1 won't work since the destructor can be called first and trying to read mutex will crash. Put lock in destructor or before the delete also won't work for the same reason.

So is there any better way in this situation? Do I have to put mutex in the global scope and inside destructor to solve the issue?

Comment: Make f1 a member function of bomb, use std::async to start a thread and store the future in a future member variable of Bomb. Make it the first member variable so the future will be destructed last. The future's destructor will then synchronize with the completion of the thread.

Comment: Poor design. Have the task destroy itself on completion or abort, and have the main thread either wait for completion or causing the abort.

Comment: Thanks, @user207421 , it's a super simplified code. The destroy action may be triggered by outside and that async queue could still be running.

Comment: Using a `shared_ptr<Bomb>` for its reference counting might work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In code, my comment looks like this :

```
#include <future>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

// do not use : using namespace std;

class Bomb 
{
public:
    void f1() 
    {
        m_future = std::async(std::launch::async,[this]
        {
            async_f1();
        });
    }
private:

    void async_f1()
    {
        using namespace std::chrono_literals;

        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{ m_mtx };
        std::cout << "wake up..\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
        std::cout << "thread done.\n";
    }

    std::future<void> m_future;
    std::mutex m_mtx;
};


int main()
{
    {
        std::cout << "Creating bomb\n";
        Bomb b; // no need to use unecessary new
        b.f1();
    }
    std::cout << "Bomb destructed\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Very interesting, but this does not constitute an answer to the question.

Comment: Hi Pepijn, thanks for sharing your solution. Is there any way to use it without making f1 a member function?

Comment: Yes pass a shared pointer `auto bomb_ptr = std::make_shared<Bomb>; auto future = std::async(std::launch::async,[bomb_ptr]{ f1(bomb_ptr); });` and then wait for the future to complete. Capturing the bomb_ptr by value will make a copy, extend bomp_ptr's lifetime for as long as the thread needs it.